# Android ConstraintLayout: extending inner Scrollview with respect to vertical neighbor-views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

**what I want to achive**

A scrollView which expends the free vertical space only if needed and a button which is appended on bottom of that scrollView but not hidden by the footer when the amount of the items in the scroll view increases.

**whats the problem**

- scrollView `android:layout_height = wrap content`:

  the button stays at the bottom of the scrollView. But then, if the ScrollView extends, the button is hidden behind the footer.
- scrollView `android:layout_height = 0dp`:

  the button stays visible while the scrollView extends the screen height. But then the button position is fixed because the scrollView is not resizing according to the amount of items.

But I didn't find a way to meet both criterias.

**question**

how do I set the constraints of this Layout to get the expected behaviour (see first image below)?

**design to achive**

[image: design to achive]

**current XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/shadeOfGrey2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/addItem"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 01"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nestedScrollView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/shadeOfGrey2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="footer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**current Android layout**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it down to what you're expecting now. Could you verify?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/shadeOfGrey2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addItem"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:itemCount="8"
            tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button 01"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/shadeOfGrey2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="footer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just keep in mind that your approach above won't be recycling any views in the `RecyclerView` adapter, so if the data is big then performance might become a concern.

Screenshots from Android Studio:

[image: 0 items]

[image: 3 items]

[image: 8 items+]

Comment: wow! Just as easy as adding `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` to the nestedScrollView! Thanks!
A few things to optimize the answer: 


- I think the button's `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" ` makes no difference. So this could be removed.
- you are using `@+id` instead of `@id` at a few constraints. I think the Plus is only necessary if you add ids, so there is no need in the references.
-maybe you could point out the issue of no recycling. I thought recycling is a matter of the underlying adapter and not of the xml-layout?

Comment: Oh, one more thing: Logcat gave me this warning: `layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap" is deprecated.
    Use layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT" and layout_constrainedHeight="true" instead.`
The Replacement works as aspected, so you should replace this in your answer to keep the answer future-safe.

Comment: Hiya @NiklasD - `constraintHeight_default` always gets me, I have yet to change it in the back of my head. I'll update my answer with the future-proofing!

Comment: Regarding the recycling - given that you're wrapping your `RecyclerView` with `layout_height="wrap_content"` in a `ScrollView`, your `RecyclerView` won't be recycling the views due to not really knowing "how many" views it can lay out to "fit to whatever constraints it has and then some". Although it is indeed the adapter that should handle recycling (and it is!), it won't know what the world looks like outside of it and can thus not decide upon how many views to inflate for the given data set. Hope that makes sense, I'm really really bad at describing stuff.